# Is there any way to repair help index for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, indexing, repair

Seems that my VS2008 help index has finally become FUBAR. It's already a known issue that after installing SQL Books Online 2008 SP1 a lot of inter-topic links break down, but this is even worse. When index entries start pointing to completely unrelated topics and things like "System.Collections.IList namespace" appear - then you know you are in trouble.

So... is there a way to regenerate the index and whatever other data structures the help has? I don't want to reinstall it to factory defaults, because there are quite a few other help collections in there too and I don't want to lose those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [H2Reg](http://helpware.net/mshelp2/h2reg.htm). I fixed my VS2005 help collection after an old version DevExpress broke it.
Another option is to remove/add every product's every components that rely on the same version of help system, reinstall if the product does not have a separate option for help, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Hmm... how do you use it for repairs? I see only install/uninstall stuff.

Comment: He, he - powerful tool indeed. Just installing it fixed the problem. :D (To those who don't understand - it also installed its own help collection which in turn forced the help engine to regenerate its indexes.)